# sapui5 - How to hide one button from SegmentedButton?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarSpacer/>
    <Button id="1" visible="false" />
    <Button id="2" />
    <SegmentedButton>
        <Button id="3" />
        <Button id="4" visible="false"/>
        <Button id="5" />
    </SegmentedButton>
    <ToolbarSpacer/>
</Toolbar>
```

All button except button 1 is visible. How i can hide button 4? 
I try in controller -

```
this.getView().byId("4").setVisible(false);
```

but button still visible.

sap.ui.version - 1.24.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i do this in controller:

```
onInit: function() {
    this.bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    // Event with app settings
    this.bus.subscribe('Hello', 'show', this.check4visble, this);
},

onAfterRendering: function(){
    this.getView().byId('4').addStyleClass('hideBtn');
},
check4visble: function(channelId, eventId, data){
    if(data.is4visible){
        this.getView().byId('4').addStyleClass('hideBtn');
    }else{
        this.getView().byId('4').removeStyleClass('hideBtn');
    }
},
```

Thanks @n01dea for explanation about bug

Thanks @Rahul for idea with class, you forgot `.getView()` in chain, be careful)

Comment: It was intentional. :) `controller.byId()` is a shortcut to `controller.getView().byId()`. Check method here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#byId

Answer (score 2):

please clear your browser cache. In chrome enter "chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData" as url. or open your application in an incognito tab: open an incognito tab in chrome with ctrl + shift + n.

it's not an error in your code.

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarSpacer/>
    <Button id="1" visible="false" />
    <Button id="2" />
    <SegmentedButton>
        <Button id="3" />
        <Button id="4" visible="false"/>
        <Button id="5" />
    </SegmentedButton>
    <ToolbarSpacer/>
</Toolbar>
```

please see this example in which your code runs just fine: [example](http://jsbin.com/juriroduri/edit?html,output)

Edit: bug in at least the sapui5 versions to 1.28.9

Comment: Your example works fine, but its dont helps me( Button still visible after clearing cache. I add my sap.ui.version to question

Comment: seems like a bug. it's there in version 1.28.9  too: http://jsbin.com/huzicuxona/1/edit?html,output.  please upgrade your sapui5 version or hide the button with custom css.

Comment: Thanks! Really seems like bug. I hope the person, who chooses sapui for our production will burn in hell. I cant upgrade my sapui.. Project too large, i dont know how many bugs get out if I do this

Comment: .. feel your pain

Comment: what says your 1.24.2 project to: "Even though we also provide older versions of SAPUI5 here, we recommend to always upgrade to the latest version! Applications using SAPUI5 1.32 or lower are affected by a security vulnerability! For more information about this issue, please refer toSAP Note 2204160." ; )

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this:

```
this.byId('4').addStyleClass('hideBtn');
```

CSS:

```
    .hideBtn{
        display:none;
    }
```

I don't think there is SAPUI5 support available for 1.24.

---

Update:
Please see this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#versionoverview.html